even if or no matter
Help the needy even if you do it with a penny.
Help the needy no matter if you do it with a penny.
Help the needy no matter whether you do it with a penny.
Which sentence sounds ok?

Giving someone a penny is not much help, but better than no help. If you cannot afford two pennnies, you help even with a penny.
The second says it doesn’t matter whether you give one penny or two. And that is false. You help more if you give two pennies. It does matter.
So grammatically both sentences are fine. As a statement of fact the second is wrong. (With few exceptions. You can often open a screw with a coin instead of a screwdriver, and in that case one penny is enough. )

even if concedes that a penny is a very small bit of help (but every little bit helps).
no matter if concedes that it is not a cause for concern if you do it  with a penny.
no matter whether ditto.


Help the needy even if you do it with a penny.

This sounds natural and clear.

Help the needy no matter if you do it with a penny.

This is understandable but slightly less common in phrasing.

Help the needy no matter whether you do it with a penny.

This is also correct and sounds formal and a bit stiff.
Overall, to me, the first sentence sounds the most natural.
